# Is the following proof about continuous function on open&closed intervals correct?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

So I want to prove that there exist no continuous onto function $f$ from $[0,1]$ to $(0,1)$. To do so, I argue as follows: Suppose for contradiction that $f:[0,1]\to(0,1)$ is an onto continuous function. Since $f$ is continuous, the pre image of any open subset of $(0,1)$ must be open. Consider in particular $(0,2/3)$ and $(1/3,1)$. Since $(0,2/3)\cup(1/3,1)=(0,1)$, the union of their pre images must be the whole $[0,1]$. But since any union of open sets is open, so must be $[0,1]$, which is a contradiction.

Anything wrong with this?

Thanks.

Comment: You don’t have a contradiction: $[0,1]$ **is** open in the space $[0,1]$.

Comment: That won't work. $[0,1]$ is open in itself.

Comment: HINT: $[0,1]$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments pointed out, the proof is wrong because the sets must be open in the induced topology of $\Bbb{R}$ on $[0,1]$, not open sets in $\Bbb{R}$ itself. One way to prove this is to use the fact that the image of compact sets by continuous functions must be compact, so $f([0,1])\subset[a,b]\subsetneq(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Without compactness, only connectedness: suppose that $f: [0,1] \rightarrow (0,1)$ is a homeomorphism. So in particular, $f': [0,1) \rightarrow (0,1)\setminus \{f(1)\}$ is also a homeomorphism, where $f'$ is the restriction of $f$ on both sides. (The restriction of continuous maps is continuous, and the same holds for the inverse of $f$; and we still have a bijection.)

But the image under $f'$ is disconnected, whatever $f(1)$ was. And $[0,1)$ is connected. Contradiction: we can't have a homeomorphism $f$.